# CSS Help in a Website

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web coding, and I need some help with CSS. However, the webpage did not turn out as I planned

I was trying to make the red section with the links on them appear in the very top left hand corner going down below the image. The red background seems to spread across the entire page rather than just the column. I would like to post pictures, but I do not have 10 reputation yet, so I can't
:(

Here is the HTML code I have been using:

```
    <!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-transitional.dtd"
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Poll Analysis</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
    <body>
        <div class= "main">
            <div class = "row1">
                <img src="Leopard-Skin-Print-Wallpaper.jpeg" />
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class = "row2">
                <div class = "row2col1">
                    <u> Links </u>
                    </br>
                    <a href="http://google.co.uk/">Google</a>                   
                </div>
                <div class = "row2col2">
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
div.main{
width:50%;
margin:auto;
background:white;
}

div.row2col1{
float:left;
margin:0;
}

div.row2col2{
margin-left:25%
background-color:white;
border:15px solid #FF0000;
}
```

Thank you all for your help in advance:

Mark Turner

Comment: swap your main and row2 divs around?

Comment: Could you possibly make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Did you want the Image or the red bar in the top left?

Comment: can you explain clearly about your problem ?

Comment: Sorry I've now edited it to explain the problem more clearly

Comment: You are missing a `;` after `margin-left:25%`

Comment: @anpsmn I feel so stupid now lol. Sorry and thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User @anpsmn solved it for me. He said "You are missing a `;` after `margin-left:25%`

I feel so stupid now and thank everyone for trying to help me.

I swear I checked it lol.

Mark Turner

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wanted?

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="main">
    <div class="row1">
        <img src="Leopard-Skin-Print-Wallpaper.jpeg" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row2">
    <div class="row2col1"> <u> Links </u>

        </br> <a href="http://google.co.uk/">Google</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="row2col2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.main {
    width:50%;
    margin:auto;
    background:white;
}
div.row2col1 {
    float:left;
    margin:0;
}
div.row2col2 {
    background-color: #fff;
    border:15px solid #FF0000;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div.main {
    width:50%;
    margin:auto;
    background:white;
}
div.row2col1 {
    float:left;
    margin:0;
}
div.row2col2 {
    background-color:white;
    border:15px solid #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="row1">
            <img src="Leopard-Skin-Print-Wallpaper.jpeg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
        <div class="row2col1"> <u> Links </u>

            </br> <a href="http://google.co.uk/">Google</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="row2col2"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: No sorry. I was tired when I wrote that and didn't explain it properly; I've now edited my problem to explain it more clearly.

Comment: @MarkTurner so the image is like a header? If it is, did you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/puoc30mx/)?

Answer (score 1):

basically each browsers have a default margins and padding size for each tags. 
so we need to clear first.   for that we are using * opreater its set a values for all tags so here i reset the values at 0.

```
*{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
```

apply this css in your html page. 
the red line start from 0  left corner. if you want red bar first swap the html on first

Comment: No sorry. I was tired when I wrote that and didn't explain it properly; I've now edited my problem to explain it more clearly.